Spark getting SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing
I'm trying to show Avro data from Kafka to console using DataStream and catch Exception
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Current parse Mode: FAILFAST. To process malformed records as null result, try setting the option 'mode' as 'PERMISSIVE'.```
How can I fix it? my config
    public static void main(String[] args) throws StreamingQueryException, IOException, TimeoutException, RestClientException {

        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", AvroDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", AvroDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "sparkGroupId");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);


        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Hello Spark").master(
                "local").getOrCreate();
        System.out.println("Hello, Spark v." + spark.version());
        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");

     Subscribe to 1 topic

        Dataset<Row> df = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "j_client")
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .load();

        String schemaRegistryAddr = "http://localhost:8081";

create RestService object
        var restService = new RestService(schemaRegistryAddr);

        //    Create REST service to access schema registry and retrieve topic schema (latest)
        var valueRestResponseSchema = restService.getLatestVersion("j_client" + "-value");
        var jsonSchema = valueRestResponseSchema.getSchema();

        var jClientDF =df.select(
                col("key").cast("string"), // cast to string from binary value
                from_avro(col("value"), jsonSchema).as("j_client"), // convert from avro value
                col("topic"),
                col("offset"),
                col("timestamp"),
                col("timestampType"))
                ;

        jClientDF.printSchema();

Stream data to console for testing

        jClientDF
                .writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .start()
                .awaitTermination()
                ;



